# How to setup routing so that upstream is selected dynamically based on a prefix in the uri

Tags: kong

In Kong, I want to setup routing as below. Specifically using Lua script because of the way Kong is setup in my organization.

My route config is as below now:

```
{
  "route_config": {
      "path":"/path/to/resource"     
  } 
}
```

Initally I had only one upstream - because of new version of implementation I have 2nd upstream now.

Backend / Upstream:
Upstream 1: (version 1)
/path/to/resource

Upstream 2: (version 2)
/path/to/resource

My requirement is to setup routing as below:
v1/path/to/resource -> Upstream1:/path/to/resource
v2/path/to/resource -> Upstream2:/path/to/resource

I am not able to find a clear documentation so that I can set/change the upstream based on request_uri in pre-function Lua script. Specifially, I want Lua script example or documentation because of the way Kong is setup in my organization. Something like

```
"pre-function": {
    "config": "if (request_uri.beginsWith('/v1/')) then set_upstream('Upstream1') else set_upstream('Upstream2')"
}
```